# Not Submitting to database, with php, mysqli

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

I can not figure out why it is breaking after passing validation and not submitting to database. Just comes up with blank screen. I have echoed out the new_password and it is encrypting it properly. Am I missing something? or doing something wrong? Any help/advice is appreciated. thanks in advance.

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])){
    //Validation and post variable stuff here but doesn't appear to be any issue with it as I have tested it alot.
}
else if(!$error_msg && !$returned_record && $_POST['register']){
    function generateHash($password_1){
        if(defined("CRYPT_BLOWFISH") && CRYPT_BLOWFISH){
    //echo "WE HAVE CRYPT BLOWFISH";
    $salt = '$2y$11$'. substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 22);
    return crypt($password_1, $salt);
     }//End If
}//End Function generateHash();

    $new_password = generateHash($password_1);
    //Build our query
$sql = ("INSERT INTO members (username, email, first_name, last_name, country, password_1) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
//Prepare our query
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or die("PREPARE DIDNT WORK");;
//Bind the fields and there parameters to our query
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $username, $email, $first_name, $last_name, $country, $new_password);
//Execute the query
$stmt->execute();
header('Location: http://someurl.com');
exit();
}
```

Comment: try : `echo $stmt->error;` after execution of the query

Comment: I tried that but no error shows up

Comment: I think i have figured out. I was trying to implement this code into a wordpress template page with a custom loop. I removed all loop/functions and It worked first try. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have figured out. I was trying to implement this code into a wordpress template page with a custom loop. I removed all loop/functions and It worked first try. So something in there was causing the issues. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the parameters, try this:

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO members (username, email, first_name, last_name, country, password_1) VALUES (:username, :email, $first_name, :last_name, :country, :password_1)");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or die("Failed Execution");;

$stmt->execute(array(
 ':username' => $username,
 ':email'   => $email,
 ':first_name' => $fname,
 ':last_name' => $lname,
 ':country' $country,
 ':password_1' $password
));
```